# Making an Array Variable Global in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting a an array variable to 0 on load of my javascript.

```
var postArray= new Array();
```

However, I used this array to hold my objects that I retrieve from localStorage. It works when I upload more blog posts that get entered into localStorage and displays. However, after I refresh the page this is called again as is an empty array and say I go to enter my 3rd blog post after i've refreshed, my localStorage is set to only having the contents of my postArray. Therefore, I'm clearing out my localStorage when I dont want to.

if you throw it into an if statement, postArray is undefined.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("posts") === null) {
    var postArray = new Array(); 
}
```

I'm trying to make the postArray global at the start yet only create a new array when localStorage is empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you throw it into an if statement, postArray is undefined.?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just get the content from the localStorage, and if it's empty, then return an empty array.

For example.

```
var postArray= getPosts();

function getPosts() {
  var posts = localStorage.getItem("posts");
  return posts ? JSON.parse(posts) : [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use document coockie instead of array !!
when page is load read the cookie content if it's empty "localStorage" then store the "whatEver you want" value on its ! 
 this is better than arrays

Comment: He is using html5 localStorage. It's kinda like a cookie.